# Avoid reading duplicate gmail emails with javamail through imap

Tags: java, imap, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap

I am using the javamail api to read my gmail box through `imap` for indexing all mail. I want to read all the folders other then the default folders. The below segment of code gives only the default folders of gmail.

```
javax.mail.Folder[] folders = store.getDefaultFolder().list("*");
for (javax.mail.Folder fold : folders) {
    if ((fold.getType() & javax.mail.Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES) != 0) {
       System.out.println(fold.getFullName() + ": " + fold.getMessageCount());
    }
}
```

I have several labels which does not show when i use the above code. Is there any way so that i can get all the user defined labels other then the default folders of gmail. Also is there any method by which i can get if any email has more then one labels and get the labels of that mail. This is to avoid the same mail reading twice. Because if any mail is marked as `important` then it comes in `INBOX`,`ALL MAILS` and `IMPORTANT` folder. So according to the above code the `INBOX` mail is read first. If i had already read the mail in  that folder i want to avoid reading the same mail in other folders and get the labels of it such as `INBOX` and `IMPORTANT` irrespective of if that mail is marked as read or unread. I am new to both javamail and imap and not able to figure how to get it to work. Please help if there is any possible method

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions

Answer (score 0):

It should work.  Try [turning on session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) to see what exactly the server is returning to you.  Also, try using list("%") to list only a single level of the folder hierarchy.

Comment: oops my bad its working was breaking the loop earlier. Is there any idea what can be done for the second part of my question which is more important for me i.e. read multiple labels mail only once and get all the labels assigned to that mail so that any duplicate data is not indexed.